# Copying folder contents from several folders

Tags: lua, directory

I have a file directory which contains folders for every month, and within those folders are several text files. In this context I would like to copy all of the text files from my `January` folder into a separate *target* folder. Then copy all of the text files within the `February` folder to the *target* folder, and so on for each month. This needs to happen sequentially and I'm not sure if I'm doing the iteration properly. I need the code to be able to run on several machines, and installing libraries on each is not possible.

Am I on the right track with the following? I'm not sure if this is the right approach to take or how to flesh this out.

```
function listdirectory(directory)
    local i, t, popen = 0, {}, io.popen
    for filename in popen('dir "'..directory..'" /b /ad'):lines() do
        i = i + 1
        t[i] = filename
    end
    return t
end

os.execute(xcopy folder_month target_folder)
```

Comment: There is an extra `end` at the end. It it a function definition?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the function name. That is correct, I've updated the post to reflect that

Comment: Why do you need to do it file by file? A simple `cp -r path/to/January new/path` would work.

Comment: This script is a smaller part of a large process. When the text files are moved into the target folder there is a separate script reading them. When that completes this script will be called again and the next months files will be needed